# Printing text to textbox and input from sql database in php

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, while-loop

I would like to ask if someone could help me with this problem.

I want to prefill the input and textbox from the SQL database. I have tried it many times and I didn't succeded.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "********";
    $password = "********";
    $dbname = "kucharka";

    $id = $_POST['id_recept'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = 'SELECT nazev, popis FROM recepty WHERE id = '.$id.'';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($result) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            echo "<li><label>Název</label></li>";
                echo "<input class='blue' type='text' name='nazev' placeholder='Název'>".$row['nazev']."</input>";
            echo "<li><label>Fotografie</label></li>";
                echo "<div class='foto'>";
                    echo "<input type='file' id='real-file' name='foto[]' hidden='hidden' multiple='multiple'>";
                    echo "<button type='button' id='custom-button' class='blue_foto'>Stiskněte</button>";
                    echo "<span id='custom-text'>Žádná fotografie.</span>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "<li><label>Druh</label></li>";
                echo "<div class='select_custom'>";
                    echo "<select name='druh'>";
                            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                            $query = 'SELECT id, druh FROM druh';
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                            if ($result) {
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['druh']."</option>";
                                }
                            }
                    echo "</select>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<li><label>Popis</label></li>";
                echo "<textarea name='text' placeholder='Popis'>".$row['popis']."</textarea>";
            echo "<li><input type='submit' name='submit' class='orange_input' value='Potvrďte'></li>";
        }
    }       
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What... exactly is not working. You will have to help us to help you

Comment: You need a form tag of your going to submit anything. You don't need the connect to the data base for every query. Your sql is open to [injection](https://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: For prefill inputs use echo “<input class='blue' type='text' name='nazev' value='”.$row[“nazev”].”'>”;

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh! You have a While Loop INSIDE a While Loop!!

And both are processing `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and therefore the inner loop destroys the `$result` used in the outer loop.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "********";
    $password = "********";
    $dbname = "kucharka";

    $id = $_POST['id_recept'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $query = 'SELECT nazev, popis FROM recepty WHERE id = '.$id.'';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($result) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            echo "<li><label>Název</label></li>";
                echo "<input class='blue' type='text' name='nazev' placeholder='Název'>".$row['nazev']."</input>";
            echo "<li><label>Fotografie</label></li>";
                echo "<div class='foto'>";
                    echo "<input type='file' id='real-file' name='foto[]' hidden='hidden' multiple='multiple'>";
                    echo "<button type='button' id='custom-button' class='blue_foto'>Stiskněte</button>";
                    echo "<span id='custom-text'>Žádná fotografie.</span>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "<li><label>Druh</label></li>";
                echo "<div class='select_custom'>";
                    echo "<select name='druh'>";

// changed code here
                            // 1 you dont need to connect twice
                            //$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                            $query = 'SELECT id, druh FROM druh';

                            // use different var here
                            // and then use it in the related function calls
                            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                            if ($result1) {
                                // and of course use a different var to hold the row data
                                // so you dont overwrite that also
                                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                                    echo "<option value=".$row1['id'].">".$row1['druh']."</option>";
                                }
                            }
                    echo "</select>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<li><label>Popis</label></li>";
                echo "<textarea name='text' placeholder='Popis'>".$row['popis']."</textarea>";
            echo "<li><input type='submit' name='submit' class='orange_input' value='Potvrďte'></li>";
        }
    }
```

> Seperate issue, you dont appear to have a `<form>` and `</form>` tag in this code. Without that the data placed in input fields will never be transmitted as a form to the PHP script for processing

**BIG NOTE**

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

So to prepare the relevant dangerous query

```
$query = 'SELECT nazev, popis FROM recepty WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($conn, $query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id_recept']);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

. . .
```